# Opening a semaphore return 0

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore, posix-api

```
char* cath="/cath";
char* cathFlag="/cathf";
char* hyp="/hyp";
char* hypFlag="/hypf";

printf("SEMS OPEN\n");
sem_t *csem = sem_open(cath, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
printf("CSEM: %d\n", *csem);
perror("ERROR: ");
sem_t *cfsem = sem_open(cathFlag, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
sem_t *hsem = sem_open(hyp, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
sem_t *hfsem = sem_open(hypFlag, O_CREAT, 0777, 0); 
printf("SEMS OPENED\n");
```

`sem_open` returns 0, `perror` writes Success, the semaphore does't open. Having looked through `sem_overview`, I saw that the problem might be in the name without a slash in the beginning, the addition did not help. There is no access to the semaphore, when `sem_post` is called shell abort process with a segmentation fault takes off. Help me understand what the problem is.
EDIT: If i reboot system(and clean semaphores?), perror returns "No such file or directory", but after returns "Success".

Comment: perror() should come before printf(). [and: diagnostic output should go to stderr, not stdout] Also: you should not dereference csem here: `printf("CSEM: %d\n", *csem);`

Comment: Check with `ipcs -a` or `ipcs -s` once they are created, before doing any other operation

Comment: @sravs "Semaphore Arrays" table is empty before and after i running the program.

Comment: @sravs: "ipcs" is not for Posix semaphores but the deprecated System V semaphores (semget(), semctl()...). Look at /dev/shm instead.

Comment: Moreover, you can't "printf" a sem_t as an int. This will not give you any coherent result.

I tried your program suppressing the printf and it works. Look at /dev/shm !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I tried and it works :

```
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{

char* cath="/cath";
char* cathFlag="/cathf";
char* hyp="/hyp";
char* hypFlag="/hypf";

printf("SEMS OPEN\n");
sem_t *csem = sem_open(cath, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
//perror("ERROR: ");
sem_t *cfsem = sem_open(cathFlag, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
sem_t *hsem = sem_open(hyp, O_CREAT, 0777, 0);
sem_t *hfsem = sem_open(hypFlag, O_CREAT, 0777, 0); 
printf("SEMS OPENED\n");

}
```

I compiled it:

```
$ gcc tsem.c -l pthread
```

I run it:

```
$ ./a.out
SEMS OPEN
SEMS OPENED
```

I looked at /dev/shm:

```
$ ls /dev/shm
sem.cath  sem.cathf  sem.hyp  sem.hypf
```